# Smoothness of a map to a circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, circles, smooth-manifolds

I am reading "An introduction to Manifolds" by Loring Tu. And trying to solve one exercise. Prove that the map $F:\mathbb R\to S^1$,$F(t)=(cost,sint)$ is $C^\infty$.I am attaching the screenshot of the exercise.Also is there a book (or a solution manualof Loring Tu) where i can find examples of the things that are given in this book so that i can use that book as a reference.[image: Screenshot of exercise]

Comment: What is the given definition of smoothness of a map? Has Tu proved any useful criteria for smoothness in the preceding text?

Comment: Take a $C^\infty$ atlas of $S^1$ and check whether apropriate compositions are $C^\infty$. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Yes @TabesBridges . Let N be a manifold. A vector-valued function $F:N\to\mathbb R^m$ is $C^\infty$ if and only if its component functions $F^1,...,F^m:N\to\mathbb R$ are all $C^\infty$. There are also other propositions.

Comment: OK, well $S^1$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. So just check that the sine and cosine functions are $C^\infty$ as functions of $t$. Now that I know you aren't working with a nonstandard definition I must agree with @freakish in being unsure of the issue. This is just a basic fact from calculus 1.

Comment: Your answer to @TabesBridges question is not applicable to this exercise. It is a theorem for maps into $\Bbb R^m$. But that is not what you have. You have a map into a manifold. (Yes, it is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$, but presumably you are supposed to prove it per the manifold structure of $S^1$, not by the embedding.) freakish has explained what you need to do: find an atlas of maps generating the manifold structure of $S^1$ (hint: you will need 2 maps to do this), and check that the compositions with $F$ are smooth.

Comment: @PaulSinclair so basically the component thing says $\iota \circ F: \mathbb R \to S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ is smooth but not necessarily $F$? (Here $\iota$ is inclusion from circle to plane.)

Comment: @BCLC - I am somewhat confused as to why you ask this, when below you quote Tu making the same point. Smoothness of $F$ is not defined as smoothness of $\iota\circ F$. Instead, it is defined by the manifold structure of $S^1$. To prove that smoothness of $\iota\circ F$ implies smoothness of $F$, you would need to bring up the manifold structure anyway and do something much more complicated than simply proving as freakish describes.

Comment: @PaulSinclair just double checking. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tu has solutions at the back of the book and in particular has one for this because it is starred.

> [image]

Btw, I think you can use Section 11 to answer this. Of course this is [inadmissible](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#116035), but

1. otherwise I don't really have anything else to say for this answer.
2. I think what follows is the more natural way to answer this exercise. Like we're just changing the range, so why would this change affect this smoothness, right?

   - 2.1. But I guess this exercise at this point in the book is good in trying to think about the use of charts and stuff in order to understand the concepts in Subection 6

Anyway here goes:

After showing that $\iota \circ F: \mathbb R \to S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ is smooth, for $\iota$ is inclusion from circle to plane (i.e. $\iota: S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$, $\iota(a,b)=(a,b)$), we can can say $F$ itself is smooth, by [Theorem 11.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjUEW.png), because $S^1$ is a regular/an embedded $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ (with $k=1$). Here, the '$f$' is $\iota \circ F$ while the '$\tilde f$' is $F$.